# How to compute the matrix representation of a linear function.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

So I have a linear function that looks like this 
$f\begin{pmatrix}x1\\x2\\x3\\.\\.\\xn\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\x1\\x2\\.\\.\\xn-1\end{pmatrix}$.

I've determined that it is a linear equation so how would I find the matrix representation of this? I know that functions like $f(x1, x2) = (x2, x1)$ would have a matrix representation like \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix} but how would I find the matrix representation for a linear function like the one above?

Comment: Compute $f$ for all the vectors of the standard base. The images give you the columns of the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a ''shift'' matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
\cdots\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$